# How to upgrade Elasticsearch from 6.8.6 to 7.16.3 in CentOs 7

Tags: elasticsearch

Good Day!

Hello Everyone, I just wanted to ask on how to upgrade my Elasticsearch: do I need to uninstall or remove the old version, or is there a way to upgrade it?

I am trying to upgrade my SugarCRM version from 10.x to 12.x since the SugarCRM 12.x requires Elasticsearch 7.16.3 I need to upgrade my current 6.8.6 elasticsearch to the required version of the SugarCRM. Now my concern is I tried to install the 7.16.3 without removing the old version and I got this error below:
[image]

Maybe what I did is wrong, hope someone can help me with my concern.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to resolve this issue, and it was successfully installed. I found a solution [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-7-0-0-is-obsoleted-by-elasticsearch-0-7-0-1-1-x86-64/180071).

**Here`s my step:**

1. Upgrade Elasticsearch from 6.8.6 to 7.16.3 run this command"wget
   [https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.16.3.rpm"](https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.16.3.rpm%22).
2. Install/Upgrade using this Command "sudo yum localinstall elasticsearch-7.16.3-x86_64.rpm"
3. Then after the upgrade or installation run this command "sudo systemctl daemon-reload"
4. Then restart the elasticsearch "sudo service elasticsearch.service restart"
5. Then check the elasticsearch status "systemctl status elasticsearch"
6. Finally, check the elasticsearch version aftert restarting "curl http://localhost:9200"

Hopefully this can help you